# How to set/update columns by using a trigger?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, trigger

I want to set/update attributes (alignment_horizontal, alignment_vertical) of a PostGIS geometry (point) by using a trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE point (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(point, SRID),
label varchar(255),
x_cord double precision,
y_cord double precision,
alignment_horizontal varchar(255),
alignment_vertical varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT point_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

CREATE TRIGGER label_alignment_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON point FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE label_alignment_triggerfn();
```

Is there any way to to set/update two columns in one trigger function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION label_alignment_triggerfn()
RETURNS trigger AS $body$
    BEGIN
    NEW.alignment_horizontal :=
        CASE
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 22.5 THEN 'Center'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 112.5 THEN 'Left'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 202.5 THEN 'Center'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 292.5 THEN 'Right'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID)))  >=  292.5 THEN 'Center'
        END;
    NEW.alignment_vertical :=
    CASE
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 22.5 THEN 'Bottom'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 112.5 THEN 'Half'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 202.5 THEN 'Top'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID))) < 292.5 THEN 'Half'
            WHEN  degrees(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_SetSRID(St_MakePoint(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord), SRID)))  >=  292.5 THEN 'Bottom'
        END;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Edit: Trigger function edited.

Comment: Yup; just set `NEW.alignment_horizontal := something; NEW.alignment_vertical := something_else; RETURN NEW;" within your trigger function.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question. Unfortunately the function isn't working (ERROR:  column "geom" does not exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should refer to every fields as NEW.field_name

ex:

```
WHEN  degree(ST_Azimuth(NEW.geom, ST_Point(NEW.x_cord, NEW.y_cord))) < 22.5 THEN 'Center'
```